# Best Method to Turn a Deep Matching Table into a Flat One

Tags: mysql

I've got a mysql table that's deep, with 4 columns

```
source1 | id1 | source2 | id2
red     |   1 | blue    |   1
red     |   1 | green   |   3
red     |   1 | green   |   6
red     |   2 | blue    |   2
red     |   3 | blue    |   2
```

What I'd like is something like....
(source)_ids, (source)_ids, (source)_ids, (source)_ids, etc, with a different column for each distinct source.

so

becomes....

```
red_ids | blue_ids | green_ids
1       |   1      | 3, 6
2,3     |   2      | NULL
```

I have tried to accomplish this with case and group_concat but haven't quite gotten my wanted results. Before I try to do this by just writing a python program, anyone know if there's a normal convention for this?

Dynamic would be way preferable, in case new sources are added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please explain your expected output  a little bit more ?

Comment: If two ids are matched, then they are referring to the same object. The end result being one object has one row of data, with all ids of the same source/object in the same column separated by commas.

Comment: Is your souce1 always contains one color ? Does your source2 contains value similar to source1 ? If yes then what will be expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem is trickier than first appears. It seems to me to be next to impossible to think of a way to construct it dynamically in SQL - so I would be sorely to tempted to switch to an application layer solution - but someone might have another idea...

```
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.id1) red
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.id2) blue
          , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.id2) green
       FROM my_table r 
       LEFT
       JOIN my_table b 
         ON b.id1 = r.id1
        AND b.source2 = 'blue'
       LEFT
       JOIN my_table g 
         ON g.id1 = r.id1
        AND g.source2 = 'green'
      WHERE r.source1 = 'red'
      GROUP
         BY r.source1
          , b.source2
          , g.source2;
```